# SharePoint Designer 2007 QUERY STRING to populate current user name in NewForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007, custom-form, xslt-list-view-web-part, query-string

I am trying to create custom NewForm.aspx. This form should auto populate current user login name display name and email details in the form when user load the NewForm.aspx.

**Note** : 
Without using jQuery and CSOM.

What is the query string parameter to get the current user info.

Is there is any way to get with the help of XSLT or else?

Comment: Have you tried setting the Default Value to `[Me]` ?

Comment: Yes [Me] working,, Similarly is there any way to get current user display name, Email and other attribute values?

Comment: You should be able to choose one of those in the people and group column: https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/01/28/88/metablogapi/1106.clip_image001_1EDC14C7.png To get more than one, maybe you should make multiple people and group columns one for each attribute.

Comment: @mike Do you have a way to auto-populate them with scripting?

Comment: Are you talking scripting like Powershell or javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSOM or [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) to get the [current user](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser&referringTitle=Documentation).

To use SPServices, you need to include the JQuery and the SPServices scripts.

```
var thisUsersValues = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldNames: ["Title", "Email"],
    debug: false
});
```

Comment: There is any way without using CSOM. Using SPD custom?

Comment: There's no method to get the current user in Designer. Though the script I gave you I would write in Designer. You can work around this by using a workflow to set a field to the Created By field, but it won't show in NewForm.aspx.

Comment: I didn't see your "no jquery." CSOM doesn't use JQuery, but I don't have the code for that.

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 0):

If no code is important to you, you could have multiple "People and Group" columns that all default to the value of [Me]. Then you have one attribute per column that you want to show from that user. One shows Email, another shows Username, another shows Display Name.
[image]

Comment: Apologies if i am not sure. I could not found Default value for **People and Group** column type. Can you please advise me?

Answer (score -1):

I got solution for my question from [Getting the Current User in SharePoint XSLT](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/getting-the-current-user-in-sharepoint-xslt)

SharePoint offers a couple of ways by which we can obtain the current user for use in a XSLT web part like DataFormWebPart or XsltListViewWebPart. All involve first setting parameters through the ParameterBindings property:

```
<ParameterBindings>
<ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="LogonUser_" Location="WPVariable(_LogonUser_)"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="LogonUser" Location="ServerVariable(LOGON_USER)"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="AuthUser" Location="ServerVariable(AUTH_USER)"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="RemoteUser" Location="ServerVariable(REMOTE_USER)"/>
</ParameterBindings>
<Xsl>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl asp" xmlns:asp="System.Web.UI.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:param name="UserID"/>
<xsl:param name="LogonUser_"/>
<xsl:param name="LogonUser"/>
<xsl:param name="AuthUser"/>
<xsl:param name="RemoteUser"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
UserID: <xsl:value-of select="$UserID"/><br/>
ID: <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:UserLookup($UserID, 'ID')" /><br/>
EMail: <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:UserLookup($UserID, 'EMail')" /><br/>
Login: <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:UserLookup($UserID, 'Login')" /><br/>
LogonUser_: <xsl:value-of select="$LogonUser_"/><br/>
AuthUser: <xsl:value-of select="$AuthUser"/><br/>
RemoteUser: <xsl:value-of select="$RemoteUser"/><br/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</Xsl>
```

Here we see different kinds of parameters:

- CAMLVariable: built in variables UserID and Today;
- WPVariable: returns one of the predefined values for *WPID* (web part
  client id), *WPQ* (web part unique id in page),  *WPR* (web part
  resources folder full URL),  *WPSRR* (web part resources folder
  relative URL), *LogonUser* (server variable LOGON_USER), 
  *WebLocaleId* (current site locale, as in CultureInfo.LCID);
- ServerVariable: returns one of the HTTP or IIS server- defined
  variables.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: clever solution!